# ASP.NET MVC - Choose which validation annotations to use

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a model with properties that look like this:

```
public class YourDetails {

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code is required")]
  [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Code length is wrong", MinimumLength = 2)]
  [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than {1}")]
  public int Code { get; set; }

}
```

The UI validation is setup the usual out of the box way with unobtrusive JS validation plugin.

**The issue:** I have 2 navigation actions, back and next. Next is fine, validation fires when things are wrong, and when things are right i.e. `.isValid()` returns true, the data is passed to the DB service etc etc.

However when I press 'back' I have a requirement to validate the form/ViewModel differently prior to saving. I.e. make sure `Code` is a positive integer, but don't bother with the `Required` or `StringLength` validation.

So basically I want to validate fully on Next but partially on Back. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've done something similar in the past the easiest way i found was to use fluent validation http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc. You can pass parameters to the validator and switch to different rule sets.

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Seems that with Fluent you can hook into the client side JS validation and choose what to validate when. Nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following conditional "Required" & "StringLength" attributes in the past and they work well.

**Required If Attribute:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Website.Core.Mvc.DataAnnotations
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

        public object OtherPropertyValue { get; set; }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(string otherProperty, object value)
            : base()
        {
            OtherProperty = otherProperty;
            OtherPropertyValue = value;
        }

        private object _TypeId = new object();

        public override object TypeId
        {
            get
            {
                return _TypeId;
            }
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.OtherProperty);
            if (property == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.OtherProperty + " not found");
            }

            // Get 
            object actualOtherPropertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            // If the other property matches the expected value then validate as normal
            if (IsRequired(OtherPropertyValue, actualOtherPropertyValue))
            {
                // Call base and validate required as normal
                ValidationResult isValid = base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
                return isValid;
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        protected virtual bool IsRequired(object otherPropertyValue, object actualOtherPropertyValue)
        {
            return object.Equals(OtherPropertyValue, actualOtherPropertyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**String Length If Attribute:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Website.Core.Mvc.DataAnnotations
{
    public class StringLengthIfAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
    {
        public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

        public object OtherPropertyValue { get; set; }

        public StringLengthIfAttribute(int maximumLength, string otherProperty, object value)
            : base(maximumLength)
        {
            OtherProperty = otherProperty;
            OtherPropertyValue = value;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.OtherProperty);
            if (property == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.OtherProperty + " not found");
            }

            // Get 
            object actualOtherPropertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            // If the other property matches the expected value then validate as normal
            if (object.Equals(OtherPropertyValue, actualOtherPropertyValue))
            {
                // Call base and validate required as normal
                return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
public class MyModel
{
    [RequiredIf("IsBack", false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsBack { get; set; } 
}
```